# How to align/place a button into the space in between two text areas?

Tags: html, css

How to align/place a button into the space in between two text areas? I want to put the button into the center space in between the two text areas, how can i do it?

```
    <textarea name="Input" id="styleid">
    TEXT
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="styled-button-2" value="Button" name="query" />
    <textarea name="Output" id="styleid" text="" disabled>
    TEXT
    </textarea>
```

This code outputs the button into the center of the two text areas but it's in the bottom part

Answer (score 2):

Use [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) to center them vertically:

```css
textarea, input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
textarea, input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="Input" id="styleid">
  TEXT
</textarea>
<input type="submit" class="styled-button-2" value="Button" name="query" />
<textarea name="Output" id="styleid" text="" disabled>
  TEXT
</textarea>
```